# How to set height of Item in list equals to its width in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have followed list of objects where I represent image + text.

Demo in <kbd>[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/LemAVZxwPTH6MdpqWogd?p=preview)</kbd>

My goal is to set height of *Item* that equal to its width.

How can I achieve that?

Here is snippets of code:

```
 <div class="list">
      <a ng-repeat="pet in pets" class="item item-thumbnail-left">
        <img ng-src="{{ pet.image }}">
        <h2>{{ pet.album }}</h2>
        <h4>{{ pet.artist }}</h4>
      </a>
    </div>
```

*Comment*

I use Ionic with Cordova but it doesn't refer to issue.

[image]

Thanks,